# Android L activity header image with transparent toolbar and collapse on-scroll

Tags: image, android-activity, header, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I have a new KitKat App and I'm trying to reproduce in my activity the layout that you can find in the new Play Store App Activity or Google+ Profile Activity.
What I am trying to achieve is to have a transparent toolbar and an "activity-header" image that will collapse on scroll:
[image: This is an example]

Is there any new appcompat widget or a pattern to follow in order to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2):

You can probably find https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar useful.
Also consult https://plus.google.com/106514622630861903655/posts/Y5iBqpzP4T9 to use the newish Toolbar.

Comment: as google released new design library collapsingToolbarLayout is the thing he should use.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html).

[Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.my/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) has everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context="com.example.YourActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"-->

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/my_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_favorite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon2"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon" />


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bea"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Abs"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black87"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Add translucent style of the status bar

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoStatusBar" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

And modify your manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:label="@string/title"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoStatusBar">
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a example code written by roman nurik ,you can learn from there https://github.com/google/iosched

Answer (score 0):

It helped me. Pay attention on ImageView:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    >
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/header"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/movie_cover"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
      />

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
      app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
      />

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```